# ASP MVC get textarea value to Html.Action

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have Viev with textarea:

```
<textarea name="textareamessage" rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
```

and I whant to pass value of that textarea to my controler by method:

```
    public void SendMessage(string messsage)
    {
       ...
    }
```

so what I nead to have after `message =` in:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@Html.Action("SendMessage", new {messsage = })">Send message</button>
```

(button is in this same cshtml that textarea ) to sen value of that textarea?

Comment: Try Javascript to get the value of th etextarea inside the form without calling the controller  . something like                $("input#message").val()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're using `Html.Action` which causes a child action to be rendered where it's called. It looks like you're looking for `Url.Action` or `Html.ActionLink`.

Second, that code is not even correct. The value of `onclick` must be some JavaScript expression. All you're passing is just a URL, which without quotes, is not even valid JavaScript. If you did add quotes, then it's just a JavaScript string, which won't do anything on its own.

Third, I'm not sure why you're even doing it that way, as your button here is a submit button, so assuming both this button and the field is wrapped in the same `form` element, then it works out of the box - no need for `onclick` or any JavaScript at all.

Finally, it seems you don't understand how client-server works. Razor (your `@Html.Action`) is processed server-side, while the field's value won't be set by the user until it's already been rendered by the server and sent to the client (the web browser) as a response. Therefore, there's no way to access the user's input before the user has even seen the form, let alone input anything.